# No connection string named 'UserEntities2' could be found in the application config file.-c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Im using EF to build an application. 
I try to inherit from a form called "GuestMenu" that is using EF model called "UserEntities2".
When I try to watch the form's designer that I inherit to ("MemberMenu") I see the following error:

> No connection string named 'UserEntities2' could be found in the
>   application config file.

The app.config file has the connection string, and I see this error only when using inheritance.

What can cause this problem ?

Member Menu form:

```
public partial class MemberMenu : GuestMenu
{
    public MemberMenu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="UserModel" connectionString="data source=ITAY-PC;initial catalog=finalDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Project23.Properties.Settings.finalDBConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=ITAY-PC;Initial Catalog=finalDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Project23.Properties.Settings.finalDBConnectionString1" connectionString="Data Source=TZAHINAKASH;Initial Catalog=finalDB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="UserEntities2" connectionString="metadata=res://*/UserEntities.csdl|res://*/UserEntities.ssdl|res://*/UserEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=**;initial catalog=***;persist security info=True;user id=**;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" `type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />`
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Thank you!

Comment: is this in the app.config of the correct Project?

Comment: Yes. And I have only 1 project in my solution.